# Add Child View Controllers to parent View Controller with gestures programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parent-child, viewcontroller

I am trying to make a hamburger menu programmatically. So far I have managed to build something that works (minus a few bugs) when using UIViews and attaching gestures to them.

Now I want to swap my UIViews for UIViewControllers that are named:

```
jobListController // This is the root controller
sideBarController // This is the side bar
```

How do I add my UIViewControllers to my hamburger menu class and apply the gestures I have created that seem to work fine on my UIViews.

I have tried adding them using: `addChildViewController(jobListController)`, but that doesnt seem to work.

I have tried to add the gesture recognizer to the viewcontrollers in my hamburger menu class but I get this error:

> Type 'jobListController' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'

I realise this is because I am not parenting the viewcontrollers to the class but I was just trying things out.

I have been tearing my hair out for a few days now and can't work out how to do this, any help would be great!

Here is my hamburger menu code (I have left the UIViews in so you can see what I am trying to do:

```
    class hamburgerMenu: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let statusBarWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow

    var sideBarOriginalCenter: CGPoint!
    var mainViewOriginalCenter: CGPoint!
    var navBarOriginalCenter: CGPoint!
    var statusBarShouldBeHidden = false

    var mainView: UIView! = {
        let mainView = UIView()
        mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0)
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return mainView
    }()
    var overlayView: UIView! = {
        let overlayView = UIView()
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:0.0)
        overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return overlayView
    }()
    var sideBarUIView: UIView! = {
        let sideBarUIView = UIView()
        sideBarUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.20, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0)
        sideBarUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sideBarUIView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.title = "JOBS"
        let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settingsImage"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HandleSettings))
        settingsButton.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
        settingsButton.width = 25
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton

        view.addSubview(mainView)
        view.addSubview(sideBarUIView)
        view.addSubview(overlayView)

        overlayView.isHidden = true

        configureGestures()
        setupLayout()

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return statusBarShouldBeHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .fade
    }

    fileprivate func configureGestures() {

        let swipeMainViewGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPanMainView))
        mainView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeMainViewGesture)

        let swipeOverlayViewGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPanOverlayView))
        overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeOverlayViewGesture)

        let swipeSideBarGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPanSideBar(sender:)))
        sideBarUIView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeSideBarGesture)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOverlay))
        overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) 
    }

    @IBAction func didPanMainView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

        if sender.state == .began {

            sideBarOriginalCenter = sideBarUIView.center
            mainViewOriginalCenter = overlayView.center
            navBarOriginalCenter = navigationController?.navigationBar.center
            overlayView.isHidden = false

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }

        } else if sender.state == .changed {

            sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: sideBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            mainView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: navBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: navBarOriginalCenter.y)

        } else if sender.state == .ended {

            let negHalfScreenWidth = ((self.screenWidth/2) * -1) / 2 // This should make -187.5 on iphoneX

            if sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    if self.sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {

                        let leftSideOfScreen = self.screenWidth - self.screenWidth

                        self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    let leftSideOfScreen = (self.screenWidth / 2) * -1

                    self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    self.overlayView.isHidden = true

                    // Hide the status bar
                    self.statusBarShouldBeHidden = false
                    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func didPanOverlayView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

        if sender.state == .began {

            sideBarOriginalCenter = sideBarUIView.center
            mainViewOriginalCenter = overlayView.center
            navBarOriginalCenter = navigationController?.navigationBar.center
            overlayView.isHidden = false

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }

        } else if sender.state == .changed {

            sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: sideBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            mainView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: navBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: navBarOriginalCenter.y)

        } else if sender.state == .ended {

            let negHalfScreenWidth = ((self.screenWidth/2) * -1) / 2 // This should make -187.5 on iphoneX

            if sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    if self.sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {

                        let leftSideOfScreen = self.screenWidth - self.screenWidth

                        self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    let leftSideOfScreen = (self.screenWidth / 2) * -1

                    self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    self.overlayView.isHidden = true

                    self.statusBarShouldBeHidden = false
                    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func didPanSideBar(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

        if sender.state == .began {

            sideBarOriginalCenter = sideBarUIView.center
            mainViewOriginalCenter = overlayView.center
            navBarOriginalCenter = navigationController?.navigationBar.center
            overlayView.isHidden = false

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.statusBarWindow?.alpha = 0.0
            }

        } else if sender.state == .changed {

            sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: sideBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            mainView.center = CGPoint(x: mainViewOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: sideBarUIView.center.y)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: navBarOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: navBarOriginalCenter.y)

        } else if sender.state == .ended {

            let negHalfScreenWidth = ((self.screenWidth/2) * -1) / 2 // This should make -187.5 on iphoneX

            if sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    if self.sideBarUIView.center.x > negHalfScreenWidth {

                        let leftSideOfScreen = self.screenWidth - self.screenWidth

                        self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    }
                }
            } else {

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    let leftSideOfScreen = (self.screenWidth / 2) * -1
                    self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
                    self.overlayView.isHidden = true
                    self.statusBarWindow?.alpha = 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction fileprivate func didTapOverlay() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            let leftSideOfScreen = (self.screenWidth / 2) * -1
            self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth/2 ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
            self.overlayView.isHidden = true
            self.statusBarWindow?.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (success) in
        }
    }

    @IBAction func HandleSettings(sender : UIButton) {

        self.navBarOriginalCenter = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            let leftSideOfScreen = self.screenWidth - self.screenWidth

            self.sideBarUIView.center = CGPoint(x: leftSideOfScreen ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.overlayView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.mainView.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.sideBarUIView.center.y)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.center = CGPoint(x: self.screenWidth ,y: self.navBarOriginalCenter.y)
            self.statusBarWindow?.alpha = 0.0
        })
        overlayView.isHidden = false
   }

    private func setupLayout(){

        mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true

        overlayView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        overlayView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true

        sideBarUIView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And the code for my 2 controllers, the code is exactly the same except the class name that I mentioned above:

class sideBarController: UIViewController {

```
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var greyBackground: UIView! = {
        let greyBackground = UIView()
        greyBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.20, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0)
        greyBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return greyBackground
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(greyBackground)
        setupLayout()
    }
    private func setupLayout(){
        greyBackground.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        greyBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        greyBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        greyBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming jobListController is a UIViewController? You need to add gesture recognizers to its view (jobListController.view). Not sure if that's the only issue you're having, but that'll fix the crash.

Comment: Yes, they are both UIViewControllers. Do you mean add the gesture recognizers within each UIViewController? At the moment I cannot even load the UIViewControllers to my hamburger menu.

Comment: That's one way you could do it, but I think the cleaner way would be to add the gestureRecognizer to the view containing the child view controllers and prevent it from blocking touches by setting cancelsTouchesInView to false. Then all you have to do once a selection is made in the side bar is to remove the old view and add the new one (and add constraints so it fills the view). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW18 is a good example for that.

Comment: Okay I think that makes sense, but how do I actually add the view controllers to my hamburger menu, I am getting errors when I try `addChildViewController`

Comment: addChildViewController does a few important things, but you have to do most of the legwork yourself IIRC. You'll probably have to manually add the child's view (e.g. jobListController.view) to the mainView when presenting it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am really confused. Can you please provide an example so I can understand a bit better?

Comment: This is an Obj C project and might be a little dated, but is similar to what you're trying to do. https://github.com/willowtreeapps/MTStackViewController